# Is there a way to put a dropdown on a cell in Excel to select the value you want used within a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm working on making an Excel Macro for grabbing data from one sheet, putting it on another sheet to then be able to look at and do some math with. So far, I am able to grab the data and I have it on the new sheet. I have 2 columns that need to be calculated using that data via a formula. However, one of the values within that formula is different depending on the item (the value that changes is a percentage). What I want to be able to do is to have something like a drop down menu on each item where I can type in/select the two values/percentages that corresponds with that item, and then those two values will be used within the formula to calculate the corresponding values in the 2 columns. Here is a picture to better show what I mean:

[image]

For example, say my discount is 50%. The formula for My Price on Item A (Cell G2) would be =SUM(E2-(E2*50%)).

Also, say the customer discount on item A is 40%. The formula for Customer Price on Item A (Cell I2) would be =SUM(E2-(E2*40%)).

The same formula is used for both columns, but the values can be different depending on the item. Each item will have a different percentages for both me and the customer.

**Basically, I would like to have a dropdown either on all the cells in Columns G and I OR on each item in column A where I'm able to type in or select the two percentages to be used within that formula, and then after selecting/typing those, the corresponding values in columns G and I will be calculated for that item.**

In my VBA code of my macro, I would ultimately like to just place the dropdowns on the needed cells, and then I can manually go through each item and set the values. That way right after my macro finishes, I am able to then go through my items and select the two percentages to be used, which will then be used in the formula to populate the values for My Price and Customer Price.

I first just want to know if something like this is possible in general, whether that be in VBA code, or just manually doing this in Excel. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use a column for each percentage? - no VBA required

Comment: If the discount is based on item, so you can have a auxiliar sheet ITEM - DISCOUNT, and and your formula will look like:  =SUM(E2-(E2*VLOOKUP(A2, YOURMATRIZ, 2 , 0)). and the Costumer will look like =SUM(E2-(E2*(VLOOKUP(A2, YOURMATRIZ, 2 , 0)-0,1))

If the proportion between the two prices is always 10%, or you can even create two columns to input the discount for each situation in the item.

After this all the sheet can be resolved, also, no need to use VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**♣ SOLVED ♣**

If I've understood you correctly, you want the drop-down list to be able to be able to operate in two 'states' - the one being its ordinary 'functionality' - that is, displaying a drop-down list; but then the 2nd state (and this is where the request becomes a little convoluted), subject to a drop down value being selected, would be to display the output / result of your previous / latest selection?

It's possible, yes, but would most likely require some bespoke VB coding with developer interface (like a drop down list that ran a macro or something of that nature).  I did actually play around with the notion of a 'dynamic' drop-down list that would append the result based on a previous selection to the drop-down list selection range itself.  Just think about how one would be able to make a different/second selection - they would select the cell containing the previous selection's result, and then be able to interact with it like an ordinary drop down list.....

Why not just have a second column where the user can select a drop-down value and then see the result display in a cell adjacent to it instead of building in all the additional headache and complexity of having a '2 in 1' single cell that served the causes of having both a 'selection list' and a "result/output" element combined into a single cell?

See google sheets [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O_9BfNrotTCBoZIHC2v54lcqCP6THs_WgY_E95BiPQo/edit?usp=sharing) for such a practicable / parsimonious soln.

Screenshot below depicting the following:

[image: Excel version of user-specific drop-down list/interaction]

This also provides an example of how your 'product-level' discounts could also feed into such a setup.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for a weird question, I tried my best to explain and show what I was trying to do, although it's hard to over text. I have since realized it would be much easier to do something like you showed here and have 2 extra columns where I can input the discount percentage, and then just have the formulas in my two columns reference those values that I can enter/change when needed