# Excel: Populate dropdown list from column A when column B has specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to populate a dropdown on sheet1 with data from sheet2 columnA.  I can do this no problem.  However, I only want the items from columnA to appear in the sheet1 dropdown if sheet2 columnB has an 'x'.

Comment: You can't do this directly. First you need to filter data to a column based on criteria `x`. then in validation rule you have to refer those filtered range. What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98gsfQY6C-RTbr4-w?e=u7gf53) refer (updates marked *):

**Demonstration**

Only values 1-10 have corresponding 'x' in 'col B' (here, d:d), whereas 101-112 correspond to 'y'.  Output as follows:

[image: Demonstration of validation list drop-down]

---

Assuming you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel,

**Lookup for validation list (F3#)**

[image: Validation list lookup values]

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C41,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x",D3:D41)))))
```

(*easily customisable for different range cols A, B - sheet_2*)

---

**Validation list**

Reference lookup range directly (*updated thanks to note by @Harun24HR)

[image: Validation List formula]

```
=F3#
```

---

**Extras**

If interested, a unique list of omitted values (cols A & B, sheet_2) can be determined in a similar *yet dependent* fashion (cf. first equation):

[image: Extras - omitted values - col A, Sheet_2]

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C41,--NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C3:C41,F3#,0))))))
```

---

Comment: No need named range. You can directly use `=Sheet_2!$F$3#` to validation list.

Comment: I thought I was going to end up having to create another column.  Thanks for the formula!

Comment: Yep, silly limitation re: validation lists I'm afraid - adding to list I'll be picking up with Bill next time we play golf ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `INDIRECT` in the data validation statement that refers to a cell with an `IF` statement.

For example, in the below picture, my dropdown is based on the formula `=INDIRECT($G$9)` and the value of G9 is determined by `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("x", H3:H7,0)), "G3:G7", "G8")`

More generally, just use `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("x", test_range)), drop_down_range, empty_cell)` and be sure to use quotes around the dropdown range.

[image]

Test 1:
[image]

Test 2:
[image]